# I want to connect my flutter application to my API but got this error

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-html

`

```
 Future<void> fetchData() async {
        final String apiUrl = 'http://192.168.100.90:4002/booking/getall';
        try {
          // Making GET request
          final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiUrl));
          print(response.statusCode);
          // Decoding response
          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            // If the server returns a 200 OK response,
            // parse the JSON
            final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
    
            // Process the data here if needed
            print(responseData);
          } else {
            // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
            // throw an exception
            throw Exception('Failed to load data');
          }
        } catch (e) {
          // Error handling
          print('Error: $e');
          throw e;
        }
      }
```

`

> I/flutter ( 2707): Error: ClientException with SocketException: Connection timed out (OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110), address = 192.168.100.90, port = 48130, uri=http://192.168.100.90:4002/booking/getall
> E/flutter ( 2707): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: ClientException with SocketException: Connection timed out (OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110), address = 192.168.100.90, port = 48130, uri=http://192.168.100.90:4002/booking/getall

I am trying to connect my API to my flutter application and I am finding a solution of this error.
what should i do now

Comment: Visit `http://192.168.100.90:4002/booking/getall` in your device's browser. Does it work? You'll need to be on the same network, and your firewalls will need to permit external traffic to the server's port 4002.

Comment: please post socket code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: http://192.168.100.90:4002/booking/getall is working well on the browser

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the port emulator can read/write(CRUD) and your server's actual port where the server is running on **(For local dev machine only)** is not the same.

Change the URL on your Flutter project code to this.

```
 uri=http://192.168.100.90:4002/booking/getall
```

To

```
  uri = 'http://10.0.2.2:5500/booking/getall';
     http://10.0.2.2:PortNumberFromError
```

And make sure you have provided the internet permission on the manifest

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```